To determine the inductance on an LC series circuit. Why do I need to determine the lowest amplitude?
I recreated the following experiment to determine the inductance of a unknown inductor:
https://diyodemag.com/education/measuring_unknown_inductors_capacitors
I used Method 3. Where I build a LC Series circuit and use a frequency generator to see on what frequency the amplitude of the waveform is the lowest.
However. After looking around. I noticed that the formula used is for the resonant frequency. Which is odd because on the resonant frequency in an LC circuit, the resistance should be the lowest thus the current should be the highest. But in this experiment it's the opposite.
I may be wrong so if anybody could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.


Which is odd because on the resonant frequency in an LC circuit, the resistance should be the lowest thus the current should be the highest.

This is correct for a series LC ciruit.

But in this experiment it's the opposite.

The experiment doesn't measure the current waveform, it measures the voltage waveform.
The function generator has an internal resistance (typically 50 ohms). When the current through the load is maximum, the drop across this resistance is maximum, leading to a minimum voltage waveform across the load. This is what you are looking for in this experiment.
Oscilloscopes always measure voltage waveforms, not current. (You can get a "current probe" that will convert the current to a voltage so the internal parts of the oscilloscope can measure it, but that isn't what's being used here)

Got it, one question though. Even tho the current increases. Why does the voltage drop?, is it because of ohm's law, as current increases, the voltage drop is greater?

@KevinMac-Ginty, yes, Ohm's Law applied to the internal resistance of the generator.
